# Scapy: Alerting when known source ip found

Tags: python, scapy

## Problem

I am trying to write a script in python that will sniff each packet on my network. I am fairly new to Scapy, but I have done some reading about the `sniff` function and especially it's parameter `prn`.
 I have discovered that using the `sniff` function with a specified `count` will capture that many packets. And that the `prn` parameter allows me to run a custom function on each packet captured. Using this knowledge I have written the following code.

### CODE

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from scapy.all import *

whitelist_src = []

def alert_me(pkt):
    if IP in pkt:
        ip_src=pkt[IP].src
        ip_dst=pkt[IP].dst

    with open('uniq_sources.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            whitelist_src.append(line)
        
    if ip_src in whitelist_src:
            print("We found a match.\n")

sniff(filter="ip", prn=alert_me, count=100)
```

### EXPECTING

I am expecting outputs of the following when an ip is found in the whitelist_src:

```
We found a match.
```

Unfortunately I am receiving these errors and I can't quite make sense of them.

### ERRORS

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./alert_me.py", line 20, in <module>
    sniff(filter="ip", prn=alert_me, count=100)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 1036, in sniff
    sniffer._run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 906, in _run
    sniff_sockets[L2socket(type=ETH_P_ALL, iface=iface,
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/arch/linux.py", line 398, in __init__
    self.ins = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(type))  # noqa: E501
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 231, in __init__
    _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

I am still learning with python as well. I hope I have provided the proper amount of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine but calling the `sniff` function requires root privileges.  That's why exception is raised.  Calling the script as root should fix the problem.

*Edit*. On a side note, I don't know if that's intended, but your `whitelist_src` will grow with IPs from your text file each time you'll receive a packet.  Moreover opening and reading the file each time you receive a packet is also time consuming.  Therefore I would suggest to move your `with` statement outside the `alert_me` function.  Of course if your text file can be updated while your script is running, this won't work.